# visual studio asp.net mvc, changing target framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Hello there Im have just changed the target framework for an asp.net mvc project from target framework 4 t 3.5,  I keep getting this error when I try to debug, or go to any controller action

'HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. '

Any ideas why I keep getting this error? as soon as I revert back to .net 4.0, everything is fine

ps could be an issue with routing as the global.asax  Application_Start() is not not hit hence route entries are not registered
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the site on IIS or Casini? If IIS, you should also check that the Application pool is targeting **.NET Runtime 2.0**